# Two divs in the single line, the right one has an image, the left one stretches and has a centered text

Tags: html, css

1. The right div contains an image of fixed size (e.g. 200x200px) and must be always sticked to the right edge of the page.
2. The left div stretches horizontally from the left page edge to the right div. It's height is the same as of right div and is equals to image height.
3. Left div also must have some lines of text centered both vertically and horizontally (centered inside left div).

```
+------------------------------------------+----------------------+
|left div (dynamic width)                  |right div (fixed dims)|
|                                          |                      |
|                   some                   |                      |
|             left-div-centered            |         image        |
|                   text                   |                      |
|                                          |                      |
+------------------------------------------+----------------------+
```

Can this be done with CSS?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/gt3on73a/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Working sample - http://jsfiddle.net/h11erm2r/

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="right"><img src="http://fakeimg.pl/250x100/"></div>
    <div class="left">
        <div>Hello world!</div>
    </div>    
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.container > div {
    border: solid 2px #888;
    height: 100px;
}

.left > div {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.left {
    text-align: center;
}

/*trick for vertical alignment*/
.left:before{
    content: '';
    display: inline-block;
    height: 100%;
    vertical-align: middle;    
}

.right{
    width: 250px;
    float: right;
}
```

Comment: Bear in mind that the left div will not grow in height with the right div using this method; you will need to explicitly set the height for it.

Answer (score 3):

Flexible box layout will help in your situation.

1. Make a flexible box container to hold the left and right divs.
2. Give the right box `flex-grow: 0` `flex-shrink: 0` and `flex-basis: 200px` so that it is static.
3. The left box needs to be stretchable, so give it `flex: 1` which grows and shrinks according to the container.
4. Horizontal and vertical centering of the text can be done using `justify-content: center` and `align-items: center`

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
}
.right {
  display: flex;
  flex: 0 0 200px;
}
.left {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex: 1 1 0;
  background: #6EAFF7;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="left">
    Centered Text
  </div>
  <div class="right">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/200x200">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `display: flex` is the best option +1, just be aware of [browser compatibility (such as IE11+ only)](http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox)

Answer (score 1):

`display: flex` is the awesome, modern way. If [compatibility is a major concern](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-table), you can't go past `display: table`.

- The outer wrapper, in this case `<body>` itself, is given `display: table` and `table-layout: fixed` to ensure the right div is kept the fixed width
- Both inner divs are given `display: table-cell`
- The left div is given `vertical-align: middle` and will grow and shrink its height based on the right div which grows its height with the image

#### Example

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
html {
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  display: table;
  table-layout: fixed;
  width: 100%;
}
body > div {
  display: table-cell;
  background: #F00;
}
img {
  display: block;
}
.left {
  background: #F90;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
}
.right {
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="left">
  Text
</div>
<div class="right">
  <img src="http://www.placehold.it/200X300" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should create a `float` div and `margin-right` div: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/taopw272/1/)

```
<style>
    .pull-right {
        float: right;
        width: 200px;
    }

    .dynamic-left {
        margin-right: 200px;
        text-align: center;
    }
</style>

<div class="clearfix">
    <div id="image" class="pull-right">
        <img src="">
    </div>
    <div id="text" class="dynamic-left">
        <span>Centered text</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Bear in mind that the left div will not grow in height with the right div using this method; you will need to explicitly set the height for it.

Answer (score -1):

@Artem take a look on this: https://jsfiddle.net/0u4f51z1/1/

```
 <div class="container">
    <div class="left">
    Ut leo dui, egestas at ultricies quis, feugiat in mauris. Curabitur nisi diam, tempus non viverra condimentum, iaculis luctus justo. Sed bibendum sit amet ante quis aliquam.
    </div>
    <div class="right">
        <img src="http://www.deftune.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/10/thexx-400x400.jpg"/>
    </div>
 </div>
```

css

```
.container {
  width: 600px;
  float:left;
}

.left {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  flex: 1 1 0;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 10px;
}

.right {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 200px;
  float: left;
}

.right img {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}
```